# Error in Query(Laravel 5.2)

Tags: php, database, phpmyadmin, laravel-5

I have a table food having fields:

- Food_id
- FoodName
- Price
- Description
- Category_id(FK)
- Res_id(FK)

And other table is Restaurant having fields:

- Res_id(PK)
- ResName
- Location
- email

I want to show location of restaurant based on Res_id.I am using laravel and I make a query that is:

```
$details = DB::table('food')
             ->select('food.Food_id','food.FoodName','food.FoodImage','food.FoodType','categories.CategoryName','Restaurant.ResName')
             ->join('Restaurant','Restaurant.Res_id','=','food.Res_id')
             ->join('categories','categories.Category_id','=','food.Category_id')
             ->where('categories.CategoryName', '=','Lunch')->get();
```

But I am unable to show location of restaurant.

Comment: What is the problem ? Also try using eloquent relations among the models like hasOne, hasMany, belongsTo etc.

Comment: `But I am unable to show location of restaurant.` Answer is You are not selecting `Location` in your select query.

Answer (score 0):

```
try this query 

$details=DB::table('food as fo')
              ->join('Restaurant as re','fo.Res_id','=','re.Res_id')   
              ->join('categories as ca','ca.Category_id','=','fo.Category_id')
              ->where('ca.CategoryName', '=','Lunch')                                    
              ->get();
```